# Multiple Domains Same Install Different Static Pages

Tags: seo, subdomains, domain, customization

I have my main domain `domain.co.nz` with a static homepage of `home` but I also have a url that is great for SEO purposes and what I am trying to do is work out how I can have my `seoDomain.co.nz` point to a specific static page with the related information but the rest of the site remains `domain.co.nz`

Comment: What you are trying to do will lead to duplicate content being served under both domain.co.nz and seodomain.co.nz. So it's a bad idea. Instead you should make unique sites on both domains.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can ... however this question is best suited for other SE forums as it doesn't relate to WordPress

In answer to your question, you login to you Domain Register and then you need to look for an option to configure *Domain Forwarding* to point all requests for `seodomain.co.nz` to `domain.co.nz/somepage`  ...

[image]

Comment: Domain forwarding uses iframes so it doesn't help in this situation. seodomain.co.nz will not have any content except an iframe that has a domain.co.nz page. This will provide zero benefit SEO wise.

Comment: There is a different version of domain forwarding for th URL, without iframe. Otherwise go lookup .htaccess and rewrite rules.

Comment: Domain forwarding without iframe is basically a 301 or 302 redirect. In that case all link juice flows to the target domain domain.co.nz. No benefit to seodomain.co.nz at all.